# Spring Security + Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, spring-security

I'm a noob in spring world and trying to get spring/AD combo to work. My config is spring 3.0.3 + spring security 3.0.3 + spring ldap 1.3+ tomcat 6.0

I get the following when i try to access my secure page:

> Reason: [LDAP: error code 49 -
>   80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9,
>   comment: AcceptSecurityContext error,
>   data 52e, v1db0]; nested exception is
>   javax.naming.AuthenticationException:
>   [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308:
>   LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment:
>   AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e,
>   v1db0]

Here's is my application-context:

```
     <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/secure/extreme/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
        <form-login />
        <logout />

          <!-- Uncomment to limit the number of sessions a user can have -->
        <session-management invalid-session-url="/timeout.jsp">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </session-management>
 <ldap-server
        url="ldap://xyz:389"
        manager-dn="CN=xyzuer, OU=xyzAccounts, DC=xyzcom, DC=com"
        manager-password="xxxxx"
    />
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <ldap-authentication-provider
        user-search-base="OU=CorpUsers, DC=xyzcom, DC=com"
        user-search-filter="sAMAccountName={0}"
        group-search-filter="member={0}"
        group-role-attribute="cn"
        group-search-base="OU=Groups, DC=xyzcom, DC=com"
    />
</authentication-manager>
```

I just have `web.xml`, `application-context.xml`, `index.jsp` and `log4j.properties` and nothing else.

Have any ideas as to where am wrong and why i get that error?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

According to this page http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/LDAP+Error+Code+49 you are using invalid credentials. Check your username/password which you use to connect to your AD.